# How to create a new folder within SSRS through .bat or .rss?

Tags: reporting-services, rss

I have a script that uploads a number of .RDL files to an SSRS report server. However, it doesn't account for if the folder it's going to is missing. I'm trying to arrange for it to create that folder, but the old vbscript CreateObject option doesn't work, and based on the fields the report database catalog table has, I don't think utilizing that will be an option.

My current .rss, called by a batch script through RS.exe:

```
Public Sub Main()
    
  Dim region As String = REGION
  Dim fLoc As String = FILELOCATION
  Dim folder As String = PARENTFOLDER
  Dim name As String = RDLNAME
  Dim data As String = DATASOURCE
 

  
  
  Dim parent As String = "/" + folder
  Dim location As String = fLoc + "\" + name + ".rdl"

  Dim overwrite As Boolean = True
  Dim reportContents As Byte() = Nothing
  Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing

  Dim fullpath As String = parent + "/" + name

  'Common CatalogItem properties
  Dim descprop As New [Property]
  descprop.Name = "Description"
  descprop.Value = ""
  Dim hiddenprop As New [Property]
  hiddenprop.Name = "Hidden"
  hiddenprop.Value = "False"

  Dim props(1) As [Property]
  props(0) = descprop
  props(1) = hiddenprop

  'Read RDL definition from disk
  Try
       Dim stream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(location)
       reportContents = New [Byte](stream.Length-1) {}
       stream.Read(reportContents, 0, CInt(stream.Length))
       stream.Close()

       warnings = RS.CreateReport(name, parent, overwrite, reportContents, props)

       If Not (warnings Is Nothing) Then
           Dim warning As Warning
           For Each warning In warnings
               Console.WriteLine(Warning.Message)
           Next warning
       Else
           Console.WriteLine("Report: {0} published successfully with no warnings", name)
       End If

       'Set report DataSource references
       'Dim dataSources(0) As DataSource
       'Dim dsr0 As New DataSourceReference
       'dsr0.Reference = region + "/MyDataSource"
       'Dim ds0 As New DataSource
       'ds0.Item = CType(dsr0, DataSourceDefinitionOrReference)
       'ds0.Name = data
       'dataSources(0) = ds0

       'RS.SetItemDataSources(fullpath, dataSources)

       'Console.Writeline("Report DataSources set successfully")
       Console.WriteLine("Report: {0} published successfully", name)

   Catch e As IOException
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
   Catch e As SoapException
       Console.WriteLine("Error : " + e.Detail.Item("ErrorCode").InnerText + " (" + e.Detail.Item("Message").InnerText + ")")
       Console.WriteLine("Report: {0} published with error", name)
   End Try
```

End Sub

Comment: The fact that you're using a command from within a batch script which you've not supplied, does not excuse you to spam the [[tag:batch-file]] tag. None of your issue is related to the batch file, so I've removed the invalid tag. Please take more care in future before you attach tags to your questions.

Comment: Since I'm already utilizing a batch script I thought there was the possibility for this to be done within that script itself, if it can't be done within the RSS. Duly noted though, next time I'll post a question specifically asking if there's a solution under that umbrella, instead of trying to save space and time for anyone involved.

Comment: If you want assistance with your batch-script, we need to see the batch file contents, not all of that irrelevant code. If you need assistance with both things, then that is two questions, both of which are unlikely to be answered by one member, well versed in both languages, and should therefore be asked and answered separately. My advice is see if your issue is resolvable with the code you've provided, instead of trying to get two sets of members working on a solution, which could very easily be invalidated by another group of members.